# Can a shell script interact with the at prompt

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script that runs schedules a command to run with "at".

The command to be scheduled is a complicated web scraping job that absolutely cannot be run before the scheduled time.

If I have in my shell script "at 9pm tomorrow" it opens an at prompt where I must then write my command. Normally I would press ctrl+D to end this prompt.

How can I write a shell script to automate this process, including the ctrl+D command to finish the command?

I have tried write to write an EOT character in my shell script but it does not work.

My problem with piping:

```
user@server:~/testing$ ls
user@server:~/testing$ touch TESTFILE | at 9pm tomorrow
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 31 at Tue Mar 12 21:00:00 2019
user@server:~/testing$ ls
TESTFILE
```

Comment: Thank you, triplee. I couldn't find that by searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the command "touch TESTFILE" to at using echo :

```
$ echo "touch TESTFILE" | at 12:35
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Mon Mar 11 12:35:00 2019
```

So in your longer example:

```
echo "youtube-dl --username 'USERNAME' --password 'PASSWORD' -o '~/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' --min-sleep-interval 30 --max-sleep-interval 60 $1 --playlist" | at $NEXTDATE
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem with piping it was that when I originally run the command it takes ages and ages, implying it's running the scrape immediately or evaluating it in some way. I read online that the thing on the left of the pipe is run immediately, and the results presented at the set date. Like I said in the original post I can't have the scrape run before the set time.

Comment: @whatscool: The solution proposed by monok seems to be correct for me, so if it does not work for you, show a minimal example which demonstrates that it does not work.

Comment: @whatscool: the command that is piped to "at" is run at the specified time. Only the echoing is run immediately. What does the code you want to run look like? (In my example it would be "myscript").  I clarified my answer above.

Comment: @monok, I edited my original question with a very basic example of the piping problem

Comment: I added my script also

Comment: You'll have to have the youtube-dl command with its arguments echoed to the pipe:  echo "youtube-dl ...." | at ..

Comment: Since you also have " in the command itself, use a single quotes ' for quoting in your arguments instead.